# Merge and synonymize [artisan] and [laravel-artisan]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The [artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artisan) tag, with around 1400 questions is about Laravel's helper utility, [Artisan Console](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan).

At some point another tag was created, [laravel-artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-artisan), which currently has only 35 questions. The post count is low enough that I could correct them manually, but the tag would continue to be occasionally misused.

These two tags should be merged and synonymized, to avoid further mischief.

Comment: Which one should be the main tag left over? I assume "laravel-artisan" but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Don't care much myself. I would personally prefer `[laravel-artisan]`, because `[artisan]` is a very generic word. But on the other hand, right now there is not much danger of ambiguity, and `[artisan]` is the older, more established tag, with 1400 questions. Although the name is hipster sounding enough that some other tool could attempt to use it at some point. Whatever floats the boat of the kind moderator that handles this.

Comment: I hope I acted quickly enough to avoid the mischief.

Comment: Mischief averted, I think. Thanks @Cody. Now burninate the whole thing and we can call it a day.